# jquery function stops others from firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, meteor

I'm building a login/join form which involves entering one field at a time (within a modal style box), which is quickly replaced by another field.

This all works perfectly until I add my code for clicking outside the modal box, as shown below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#loginJoinBackground").click(function(){
        $("#loginJoinBackground").fadeOut(300,function(){});
    });

    $("#logins-box").click(function(){
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Now, that also works fine for what it is supposed to to.
The problem is that when I have that code in, it stops the other functions from firing. Is there something obvious that I am missing?

Edit: I am using meteor so perhaps that might be affecting things differently, the code that fails to fire as a result of the above is below:

```
$(document).on("click", "#loginB", function(){

logMeIn($("#logU").val(), "");
})
 function logMeIn(emailVar, passwordVar = ""){
 Meteor.loginWithPassword(emailVar, passwordVar, function(err){
  console.log(err.reason);
  if(err.reason == "Incorrect password"){
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#spanEmailLogin").hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 200);
        $("#spanPasswordLogin").show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 200);
        $("#logP").focus();
  }



  else{
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#spanEmailLogin").hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 200);
    $("#spanPasswordLoginForm").show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 200);
    $("#passwordForm").focus();
  }
});


  }
```

Comment: would like to check your HTML as well

Comment: Pass the event object to the click callback. `$("#logins-box").click(function(){` ==> `$("#logins-box").click(function(event){`

Comment: @Rivz11 Did you check your browser console output for errors?

Comment: @Tushar I've given it a try but unfortunately still having the issue, added a bit to my question around the code failing to fire... Obsidian no errors coming up, just nothing happens at submit stage :/

Comment: I think you are missing the event argument for the function.for event.stopPropogation() to work there must be an event argument!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need jquery for `click` event. You should use `Template.events`

Try this and let me know:

```
Template.youTemplate.events({
  'click #loginB': function (e,t) {
    var emailVar = t.find('#logU').value
    var passwordVar = t.find('#logP').value
    Meteor.loginWithPassword(emailVar, passwordVar, function(err){
      console.log(err.reason);
      if(err.reason == "Incorrect password"){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#spanEmailLogin").hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 200);
        $("#spanPasswordLogin").show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 200);
        $("#logP").focus();
      } else{
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#spanEmailLogin").hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 200);
        $("#spanPasswordLoginForm").show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 200);
        $("#passwordForm").focus();
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much @yudap , this almost worked, it only wasn't able to detect the value of emailVar and passwordVar. So I just added in a couple of lines to your suggestion and it worked! Lines I added after the click event and before the Meteor.loginWithPassword bit: var emailVar = document.getElementById("logU").value;                                                          
      var passwordVar = document.getElementById("logP").value;

Comment: @Rivz11 No need `document.getElementById`. It will search the whole document. This will slow! For faster, use meteor way to find id in defined template. See revised answer

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to call the `preventDefault()` method instead of `stopPropagation()` ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#loginJoinBackground").click(function(){
        $("#loginJoinBackground").fadeOut(300,function(){});
    });

    $("#logins-box").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        //event.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Comment: stopProppagation might be the cause for not firing any other event when this click event is trigger. Because stopPropagation is stop to bubble any other event after execution.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work - clicking inside the modal causes it to close in that instance.

Comment: @ArpitJain indeed - I tried using return false instead of stopPropagation, which has the same results mentioned in the question strangely enough..

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#loginJoinBackground").click(function(){
 $("#loginJoinBackground").fadeOut(300,function(){}); });
 $("#logins-box").click(function(event){
event.stopPropagation(); 
}); 
});
```

this ***may*** work im not sure